# Are there any tools for editing Sql Server spatial types in Silverlight?

Tags: sql-server, silverlight

I see from [this post](http://www.gisbelowsealevel.nl/Blog/post/Spatial-Web-Services-in-Silverlight.aspx) that I can tweak RIA Services to transmit Sql Server spatial types.  What I'd like to do is edit these spatial types.  Does anyone know of any tools that would run in Silverlight that would support this?

Answer (score 1):

[silverlight editing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/editing_features.htm)

[create feature layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/help/creating_featurelayer.htm)

Edit:

it looks like someone was doing this a year ago maybe he had some luck by now.
[Will Kimrey](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=158&f=2455&t=293269&g=1)

Comment: I'd like to directly edit a Sql Server table that contains a spatial column and exposed via RIA services without using arcgis server or arcsde.

Comment: Looks promising, however "This Forum is closed for replies." Wonder where Will Kimrey hangs out these days.

Answer (score 1):

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//002q0000006p000000.htm

> By default, ArcSDE geodatabases in SQL
>   Server use the ArcSDE compressed
>   binary type, so if you want to use the
>   Microsoft geometry or geography types
>   for storage, you must either (1)
>   change the GEOMETRY_STORAGE parameter
>   under the DEFAULTS configuration
>   keyword in the SDE_dbtune table to
>   GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY or (2) specify a
>   configuration keyword that designates
>   a GEOMETRY_STORAGE parameter of
>   GEOMETRY or GEOGRAPHY when creating
>   feature classes.

Using the Silverlight API editing that Brad suggested will edit the SQL Spatial Types if the GEOMETRY_STORAGE parameter is set to not use the ArcSDE compressed binary type.  This is probably the best option if you are not using versioned data and you want to make your edits directly on the map, as opposed to editing the string representation of the geometry.

Comment: All I have for this task is SQL Server 2008.  I don't have AGS or arcsde.  I want to leverage RIA Services.

Comment: I'm looking through the blog post on GISBelowSeaLevel.net.  It looks like he's using the ToWpfGeometry() method to render the geometry as a string in the GridView.  Could you reverse that function to take in a Silverlight geometry and return a SQLGeometry?

Comment: Yes,  I hadn't thought about that. So I guess if there is a toolset that lets me edit wpf geometries I could adapt that. Do you know of one?  (e.g. Something that add/moves vertices from polygons).

Comment: You could probably use the new editing capabilities that come with the 2.x API, and then send the modified geometries to that method once the edits are complete.  Alternatively, the lead developer on the ESRI Silverlight team wrote an editor for 1.x API last year: http://resources.esri.com/arcgisserver/apis/silverlight/index.cfm?fa=codeGalleryDetails&scriptID=16273                       Here is a sample app:   http://serverapps.esri.com/SilverlightDemos/EditGeometry/

Answer (score 1):

Not seen any direct editing in sliverlight tool but have edited shapefiles and reloaded using
SharpGIS

http://www.sharpgis.net/page/SQL-Server-2008-Spatial-Tools.aspx

Maybe of interest:
http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Map/Shapefile/World

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use the .NET SqlGeometry / SqlGeography from the
 [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee642046.aspx)
 namespace to roll your own editing?

There are some extras in the [SQL Server Spatial Tools](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Contents&referringTitle=Home)  that may add some extra functionality.  These types can both be used from within SQL Server or directly through the CLR, so I can't see why you wouldn't be able to use them in a Silverlight application (although I have not tried).

EDIT:
[Another post explaining more (and maybe it's not possible)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382/how-can-i-use-sql-servers-spatial-types-from-a-net-application) looks like the Silverlight API isn't able to reference the SQL types.